# Using the browser to transform an XML document

Tags: html, xml, xslt, simplexml

I have XML data and am trying to use XSL to format the data. I am following some tutorials. When previewing the XML in Internet Explorer the data is on one line; when previewing with Firefox I get the error message:

> Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.

Here the XML:

```
 <?xml version= "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
    <countries>
        <country> 
            <countryname>United States</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>United Kingdom</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Deutschland</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Osterreich</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Espana</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>France</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Italia</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>China</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Hong Kong</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Japan</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Singapore</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Taiwan</countryname>
        </country>

        <country>
            <countryname>Malaysia</countryname>
        </country>
    </countries>
```

Here is the XSL:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/countries">
<html>
<body>

    <xsl:for-each select="country"

    <xsl:value-of select="countryname"/><br/>

    </xsl:for-each>

</body>
</html>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylsheet>
```

Why does the browser not display the XML document as described by the XSL template?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to add an error message AND which browser you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Missing Bracket

`<xsl:for-each select="country"` must be `<xsl:for-each select="country">`.

Note the closing `>`.

## Extra Space

Also, you may wish to remove the leading spaces on the first line of the document, if they exist:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

vs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

## Typo

`</xsl:stylsheet>` must be `</xsl:stylesheet>`

After making these changes, the list of countries appear.

## Debugging

Consider editing XML and XSL using a text editor that has syntax highlighting and would alert you visually to such errors.

[image: Syntax Highlighted Example]